# Updating single Column of List without Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, linq, list, select

I have a `List`

```
List<Myclass> li = new List<Myclass> ();
```

where `Myclass` is

```
public class Myclass
{
    public string ExamName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Marks { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> OutOfMarks { get; set; }
    public string GradeMarks { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> markEaxmTotalOverAll { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MarksExamTotalMarksTypeWise { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MarksExamOutOfMarksTotalOverAll { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MarksExamOutOfMarksTotalMarksTypeWise { get; set; }
}
```

li contains almost 10000 items 
i want to set `markEaxmTotalOverAll` value to  50 in all 10000 items 
but don't want to do it with loop , Is there any way to update it , I tried this code

```
li.Select(s => { s.MarksExamTotalOverAll = 50; return s; });
```

but its not working

Comment: ...why don't you want to do it with loop?

Comment: not any specific reason,just dont like to use loop

Comment: @coAdin foreach specifically or not any loop?

Comment: I just don't get what this fascination is of "don't want to use loops, want to use LINQ"....

Comment: yes you can say i want to do it with LINQ

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the Q of LINQ says, the basic usage of LINQ is to *query*, not to *update*.

The less verbose form of foreach is the `ForEach` method of `List<T>`:

```
li.ForEach(z => z.MarksExamTotalOverAll = 50);
```

Comment: Could it be possible to add a where clause? I mean, update only specifics objects? Can someone help me, please?! Tks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code which runs specified task in a parallel manner

```
 List<Myclass> li = new List<Myclass>();
 Parallel.ForEach(li, l => l.MarksExamOutOfMarksTotalOverAll = 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
li.ForEach(x=>x.MarksExamTotalOverAll = 50);
```